# ASP.NET Web Service for android

Tags: android, .net, sql, sql-server

I want to create a web service that receive a message from android app and get data according to message from sql server database.... so please any tutorials or examples with explanation of code

Comment: have you tried Google?

Comment: yup but i didn`t understand anything...
I`m just android and c# programmer and not have any experience in ASP.NET so I selected it as i have experience in c# syntax

Answer (score 2):

just get it from the original source , hope this helps
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14957/Web-Services-in-C-and-Net

anyway, if you're doing it to test your android app , it's much easier to accomplish in eclipse with tomcat , at least I find it so